# Looking up and dividing one range by another

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two sets of data in two tables: in this format:

Table 1

```
A 1 2 4 5 6 7 8 3 2 1 4
D 5 6 7 8 3 2 1 4 5 6 7
E 1 4 5 6 7 5 6 7 2 1 4
```

Table 2

```
A 1 4 5 6 7 7 6 7 2 1 4
B 5 6 7 8 3 2 1 4 5 6 7
C 1 4 5 6 7 5 6 7 2 1 4
```

Now, I want to get a ratio of sums of values is A in table 1 to sums of values in A in table 2 (and for every other column label that matches). I need to lookup the name, pull 11 values, sum them and divide by sum of corresponding values from second table to get a required ratio of one to another.

Assuming I cannot add an additional column at the end with sum of that row of values and vlookup that (it's the easiest way to resolve it I think), is there another way to achieve what I want?

Comment: What is the question? You've explained what you want to do, so not sure where the fault/issue is.

Comment: @DaveRook Assuming I cannot add an additional column at the end with sum of that row of values and vlookup that (it's the easiest way to resolve it I think), is there another way to achieve what I want?

Comment: But if can't add an extra column, where do you want to show this information (or is that the issue)

Comment: @DaveRook The result of a calculation (ratio) will be used on a seperate worksheet.

Comment: What have you already tried that is not working for you? If you share the formula you are using, maybe someone can help you get it to work.

Comment: @CharlieRB I'm looking for valid suggestions on the stated question and not for help on formula troubleshooting.

Comment: Sorry. Let me rephrase it. It would be nice to know what you've already attempted in order to accomplish what you've stated in your question. There is a reasonable expectation here that the asking party has made some effort before asking the question. Comments are added to gather more information and clarification in order to help you for free. [ask] may help clarify this for you.

Comment: @CharlieRB Am I to understand that you're holding back your answer in anticipation of me somehow proving that I've made "some effort" in resolving this myself?

Comment: +1 I think due diligence has been done here. He had a solution in mind, but it required an addition to the original data, which he wanted to avoid. No need to belabor the point.

Comment: There is nothing to prove to me. Please understand the questions asked in the comments are to gain better understanding for the purpose of improving the question and to provide as complete an answer as possible. None of this is a personal attack on you.

Comment: @CharlieRB Actually in your three comments you've not asked once for more information or for any clarification on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the building blocks you can use to get what you want:

- Prepare an unduplicated list of the labels (or codes) in the first columns of both tables (A, B, C, D, E in your example).
- Use `MATCH` to identify the row in which each of the labels in the unduplicated list is found in each table. An assumption here is that each label occurs only once, or not at all, in each table. For example, the values of the MATCH for A in each table will be 1 and 1, respectively.
- Use `OFFSET` to return the row of values for each label in each table. The MATCH result is used here to determine the appropriate row offset. OFFSET is an array function.
- Use `SUM` to add up the row of values for each label returned by OFFSET.
- Divide the `SUM` for the row from Table 1 by the `SUM` for the row from Table 2 (for each of the labels in the unduplicated list).
- Use `IFERROR` to filter out error results in the divisions, which will occur because of labels that occur in one table but not in the other. In the example, because A is the only value that occurs in both tables, the formulas for B, C, D, and E will all return error values.

These functions can be combined in a single formula for each row in the unduplicated list of labels.